# GFS Didot accented letters not working in LaTeX

Tags: fonts

I am trying to use GFS Didot in pdfTeX to typeset a short French music article, but some of the accented letters are not working. While I could do without accented capitals, several essential accented lowercase letters are not showing up (à in upright; à, è and ù in bold; é and è in italic).

Am I mistaken that GFS Didot should contain this letter? It is in this specimen: http://www.greekfontsociety.gr/images/Didot%20Specimen.pdf

However, it is not in this font table: http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/gfsdidot/gfsdidot.pdf

(In fact, the font table seems to have generated the same errors that I have, including some weird strange boxes for the accented capital A letters.)

How can I get this to work? Where could I look for the answer?

(FYI, I am newish to LaTeX, running TeX Live 2015 on a Mac. Compiling with TeXShop.)

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{gfsdidot}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\linespread{1.1}

\begin{document}

% ALPHABETS
\noindent a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z \\
\textbf{a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z} \\
\textsc{a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z} \\
\textit{a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z} \\
A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z \\

% DIACRITICS
\noindent é à è ù â ê î ô û ç ë ï ü \\
\textbf{é à è ù â ê î ô û ç ë ï ü} \\
\textsc{é à è ù â ê î ô û ç ë ï ü} \\
\textit{é à è ù â ê î ô û ç ë ï ü} \\
É À È Ù Â Ê Î Ô Û Ç Ë Ï Ü

% EXAMPLE
% text from Wikipedia: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonie_tonale
\section{Exemples d’harmonie tonale à quatre voix}
\subsection{Passage du do majeur au ré majeur}
Partons de l'accord de do majeur agencé comme ci-dessous et voyons à partir d'une basse en ré comment passer en ré majeur. Cette succession d'accords se trouvera très fréquemment dans la tonalité de sol majeur par exemple où il correspond à un enchainement des deux degrés forts IV et V. Cet exemple a pour vocation de présenter les raisonnements associés à la réalisation musicale dans l’harmonie tonale classique.

\begin{center}
    \begin{lilypond}[staffsize=18]
        \new Staff {
            { c'1 d'1 \bar "||" }
        }
    \end{lilypond}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It works with `fontspec` if I set GFS Didot as the main font and compile with `xetex` or `luatex`, so the problem seems to be in the `gfsdidot` package.

Comment: The problem is in the fonts for `pdftex` that are malformed. I suspect a bad bug in the `.pfb` file, because the reencoding files seem to be good. Note that in the tfm file several characters are assigned only a width and not a height nor a depth, showing that something is amiss.

Comment: If I try `pfbtopfa GFSDidot.pfb`, I get an error from Ghostscript, so the problem seems really to be in the `.pfb` file.

Comment: Merci, Thérèse - it works! I tried `luatex` but didn't try it with fontspec. T'oh!

Comment: I would prefer to use `pdftex` with lilypond, how easy or hard would it be to fix the `.pfb` file?

Comment: @egreg: The afm shows boundings boxes of size zero, e.g. `C 224 ; WX 490 ; N agrave ; B 0 0 0 0 ;` so I think too that something is wrong with the pfb.

Comment: @DevonLePage Not only the `pfb` file should be rebuilt, but also all accompanying metric files for cooperation with TeX. `:-(`

Comment: @egreg Oh darn! `:-(`

Comment: You could recreate the pfb etc with e.g. autoinst from the otf. Or make a bug report ...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Apologies for being naive, but where or to whom do I make a bug report?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Will check out autoinst, tho. Thanks for the direction!

Comment: As the fonts themselves seems to be broken, I would write to the greek font society.

Comment: The `gfsdidot` package has been updated: `gfsdidot.sty` 2018/01/02 v1.1. The accented letters have been added, but unfortunately several of the accents are misplaced.

Answer (score 4):

Use `xelatex` and `fontspec`, and everything will be fine. Btw, it is better to load `french` as a class option nowadays.

```
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{GFS Didot}
\usepackage{babel}
\linespread{1.1}

\begin{document}

% ALPHABETS
\noindent a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z \\
\textbf{a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z} \\
\textsc{a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z} \\
\textit{a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z} \\
A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z \\

% DIACRITICS
\noindent é à è ù â ê î ô û ç ë ï ü \\
\textbf{é à è ù â ê î ô û ç ë ï ü} \\
\textsc{é à è ù â ê î ô û ç ë ï ü} \\
\textit{é à è ù â ê î ô û ç ë ï ü} \\
É À È Ù Â Ê Î Ô Û Ç Ë Ï Ü

% EXAMPLE
% text from Wikipedia: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonie_tonale
\section{Exemples d’harmonie tonale à quatre voix}
\subsection{Passage du do majeur au ré majeur}
Partons de l'accord de do majeur agencé comme ci-dessous et voyons à partir d'une basse en ré comment passer en ré majeur. Cette succession d'accords se trouvera très fréquemment dans la tonalité de sol majeur par exemple où il correspond à un enchainement des deux degrés forts IV et V. Cet exemple a pour vocation de présenter les raisonnements associés à la réalisation musicale dans l’harmonie tonale classique.

%\begin{center}
% \begin{lilypond}[staffsize=18]
% \new Staff {
% { c'1 d'1 \bar "||" }
% }
% \end{lilypond}
%\end{center}

\end{document}
```

(I commented out the `lilypond` environment, as it is not installed on my system).

[image]

Comment: Should I use french as a class option in `luatex` as well?

Comment: I don't know, but that must be explained in the documentation of `frenchb` (p.  3 of the French documentation), so that all extensions that depend on the language know about the language options. I don't see why it should be different with lualatex…

Comment: I see! I will check the documentation. Thanks!

Comment: @DevonLePage Also see the documentation for `microtype`, which can take `babel` and French into account.