# Accent Mark on Capital C

Tags: accents

I am writing to a professor named is Branko Curgus. The C in Curgus has an acute accent on it, as you can see on his webpage here

http://faculty.wwu.edu/curgus/

I can get tex to put the proper accent on certain letter like E, but when I switch it to a C it disappears. I am using the package [utf8]{inputenc}.

To be clear, this one works

> Dr. Branko \'Eurgus

But this one makes the C disappear altogether

> Dr. Branko \'Curgus

Also, I am using letter document class. This is where/how it appears in my script

> \begin{letter} 
>   {Dr. Branko \'Curgus\ 
>   Department of Mathematics\
>   Western Washington University\ 
>   Somewhere, Somewhere \ }

Photos of code and output:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why not  Dr. Branko Ćurgus with his name taken from the site?

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke Well, I just tried that and it just put a question mark where the C was...

Comment: Load `\fontspec` and compile with `xelatex`  or `lualatex`.

Comment: @PrinceM Can you show a minimal example? The body of the letter is of course unimportant. Any version of LaTeX should produce `Ć` when the input is `\'C`

Comment: Edit, it appears to work when I type it in with E without copy and pasting but still disappears for C? @egreg

Comment: The problem is that the GFSDidot font doesn't contain that glyph. If you remove the `\usepackage{gfsdidot}` line, you should get the Ć.

Comment: @AlanMunn  Alas, you are my savior. It worked. Thank you to everyone who commented above to help me solve my problem.

Comment: The GFS Didot font is for typesetting Greek, and not really suited for Latin text. As the Latin font is supposedly based on Palatino, you might want to try the `tgpagella` or `pxfonts` packages instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We could delete this question, but perhaps I'll turn it into a bit of a lesson both on how to ask better questions, and more importantly, how to learn to diagnose problems that will inevitably arise when you use a system like TeX.  Please don't take this answer as criticism but rather as hopefully helpful information for the future.

One of the most important things you can do to diagnose a problem is to create a Minimal Working Example which shows the problem that you asking about. We have plenty of information on how to do that on the Meta site.  Once you've done that you should put that code (not a screenshot of your editor) in your question. This allows people to see what you are (or aren't) doing very quickly, and greatly improves you chances of getting a quick answer.

- [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)

Now, the *most minimal* document that you could have created would have been the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\'Cerda
\end{document}
```

But this document *doesn't* show the problem, so in effect it is too minimal. But had you created it, you would have seen immediately that you can in fact produce the character you were looking for.

So this leads quite quickly to the source of the problem in your actual document.  Since there is a package loaded for a font, and you are having problems with the font, we can add that package to your document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{gfsdidot}
\begin{document}
\'Cerda
\end{document}
```

Now we see the source of the problem.  Of course by doing this, you wouldn't have needed to ask the question. :-) (Or perhaps you could have asked a question about why the two documents behave differently.)

And the answer is:

As Robert notes in the comments, the GFSDidiot font is really designed for Greek and provides limited support for Latin characters. Because of this, it doesn't contain the Ć glyph, and it also seems that it isn't set up properly:

- [GFS Didot accented letters not working in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/274981/2693)

Comment: `the GFSDidot font simply doesn't contain the Ć glyph` is not really the answer, as latex should be able to construct a composite letter, like it does for `\'M`, `\'q` or even `\'*`, which all don't exist as glyphs in the font. The problem is that GFS Didot doesn't _undeclare_ the glyphs that it doesn't contain. So I would say it's not really suited for non-Greek text (try `\'A` or ``\`A``).

Comment: IMHO this is even more than a problem of MWE. 'I want to put an accent on a letter' doesn't belong to any TeX forum; check your code, ask your friend, read a book on LaTeX and Google your question first. Being helped by great power users like TeX.se top team is also something one should deserve

Comment: @zozor We all have to start somewhere. This was not so obvious a problem; it's caused by a particularly odd font package. So it's not as simple as "how do I put an accent on a letter". More importantly, those of us who are very active on TeX.se pride ourselves in creating a very friendly environment.  There's very little to be gained from constant RTFM type answers or comments. Questions that elicit RTFM responses most often have well written duplicates on the site. So instead of trying to change people's behaviour by telling them what to do, find a duplicate on the site and link to that.

Comment: @Robert: Undeclaring glyphs would remove them for other T1-encoded fonts too. Also as you can see in the question Alan linked to there is a problem with the pfb of gfsdidot. Actually while I can see the Ć in the output I can copy and paste it .... Beside this gfsdidot does funny things with the OT1 encoding. I would simply avoid the package.